# how to debug requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm getting a console error when requireJS is trying to load a module that is no longer there; so the GET request is returning 404. My problem is, in Google Chrome console, the stack trace is only showing the calls from within requireJS and not my code so I don't know where the problem is occurring.

How can I find out where in my code is this call being made to requireJS to fetch the module?